# node.js parse error in module past file end

Tags: node.js, parse-error

I'm building my first project with node.js and I've got a parse error on a module I've made

```
"...exporter.js:700" });
```

However, exporter.js is only 699 lines long. What does that mean?

Comment: Run your code through jshint to check for common errors. I bet you'll find it! http://jshint.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, jshint doesn't like a lot about my coding style and won't parse the whole file. It stops at about 50% after giving my a million warning (no errors though).

Comment: Hmm. Try disabling all the extras or just post your code :)

Comment: Posted the last half of my code, and found a stray } now it's on to more reasonable errors. Thanks, I didn't know about jshint. Cool tool.